# Order column based on data in another column in R (tidyverse)

Tags: r, tidyverse

Ideally looking for a tidyverse solution to the following.

I have data which comes to me in random order.  Every row has a unique four digit identifier (labeled ID below).  I group it initially by a date column (simple enough).  Another column indicates what the previous row should be within that date (labeled Prev_ID below).  The first row for a given date has an Prev_ID which will not refer to something within that date.  I want an output ordered like the following:

```
Date    ID    Prev_ID
1/1    8731    1436  
1/1    4522    8731
1/1    1301    4522
1/2    6675    3690
1/2    9123    6675
1/2    0025    9123
```

I've tried creating some loops to do this but I'm getting a bit lost in the weeds, and because I'm dealing with a lot of data, I'm worried about it being slow.  Seems like there should be a simple solution here.

Thoughts?

Comment: Input data would be the same six rows in random order

Comment: `dat <- dat[sample(nrow(dat)),]`?

Comment: It's courteous to provide sample input data that's ready for use--it's an easy step you can take one time instead to save every single person who works on your problem from having to do individually. It can also help make the question clearer.

Comment: Fair, my bad.  This is my first time asking a question here, so I wasn't sure how to provide the sample data (though now that I see what @r2evans did, I realize that it would have been fairly simple.)  Will do in the future, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Randomize the row-order:

```r
set.seed(42)
dat <- dat[sample(nrow(dat)),]
dat
#   Date   ID Prev_ID
# 1  1/1 8731    1436
# 5  1/2 9123    6675
# 6  1/2 0025    9123
# 4  1/2 6675    3690
# 2  1/1 4522    8731
# 3  1/1 1301    4522
```

Sort based on `Prev_ID` in `ID`:

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  mutate(otherrow = match(Prev_ID, ID)) %>%
  arrange(Date, !is.na(otherrow), otherrow) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-otherrow)
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   Date  ID    Prev_ID
#   <chr> <chr> <chr>  
# 1 1/1   8731  1436   
# 2 1/1   4522  8731   
# 3 1/1   1301  4522   
# 4 1/2   6675  3690   
# 5 1/2   0025  9123   
# 6 1/2   9123  6675
```

Note: your `Date` as a string is not going to be good for sort-order in the long term once you get month-days over 9, noting that `sort(c("1/2", "1/11"))` puts `1/11` *before* `1/2` due to the lexicographic sort priorities. You can either convert to a "real" `Date`-object (you'd need the year component), or you can convert the month-day to be zero-padded with `dat$Date <- sub("/([0-9])$", "/0\\1", dat$Date)`.

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(Date = c("1/1", "1/2", "1/2", "1/2", "1/1", "1/1"), ID = c("8731", "9123", "0025", "6675", "4522", "1301"), Prev_ID = c("1436", "6675", "9123", "3690", "8731", "4522")), row.names = c(1L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```